# \[ranked-choice-voting] = synonym for \[voting-systems]?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I don't think there should be separate tags for each individual voting system

Answer (score 2):

If this ever does happen, it’s probably also worth  making [range-voting](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/range-voting) and [first-past-the-post](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-past-the-post) duplicates, as well as maybe some others.

Comment: Yes, that would be best